# How to convert values ( in time format) into numbers (float)

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, data-conversion

I have combined hundreds of excel files.Then I would like to make a pivot table. However, I found some values in weight column are in date format, causing the program failed to calculate. How can i turn them into number (float)?

Problem found in excel files:

Code:

```
li=[]
os.chdir('/content/drive/MyDrive/WEM')
allFiles=(glob.glob("*/*.xlsx"))

for file in allFiles:
  df=pd.read_excel(file,index_col=False)

  li.append(df)

WEM=pd.concat(li,axis=0,ignore_index=True)

WEM['Date']=pd.to_datetime(WEM['Start Time'],format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
WEM['Month']=WEM['Start Time'].dt.month

pd.pivot_table(WEM,index=['Month'],values=['weight (KG)'],aggfunc=[np.sum])
```

Comment: what does date 1900-01-11 supposed to be in float?

Comment: Yes, if i change the cell format in excel, "1900-01-11" has a value of 11.5.

Comment: I checked that "11/01/1900 " is actually "11/01/1900  12:00:00". When I change it to numeric value in excel, it is 11.5.

Comment: Excel has no datetime type as such. Dates in Excel are actually stored as floats (number of days since 31 Dec 1899). If you change the display formatting to General on that column the "dates" will disappear.

Comment: Does it help if you include `dtype={"weight (KG)": float}` in the call to `read_excel`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter all rows with date format and convert them to values like below:

Suppose this dataframe:

```
>>> df
       weight
0          0.
1         22.
2          7.
3        20.5
4  1900-01-11  # <- should be 11.5
```

```
df['weight'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['weight'] + ' 12:00', errors='coerce') 
                - pd.to_datetime('1900-01-01')) \
                    .dt.total_seconds().div(60*60*24).add(1) \
                    .fillna(df['weight']).astype(float)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   weight
0     0.0
1    22.0
2     7.0
3    20.5
4    11.5
```